# Co-ordinator layout or Bottom sheet behaviour

Tags: android, gmail, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I like to create a layout as the Gmail profile view

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly0fR.png)

And when the user scrolls up the profile image should translate to an action bar Icon as the same as gmail profile view.

I create view like this by using the bottom sheet behaviour but the movement of the User icon to  the app Icon while scrolling up is not done.

[scrolled Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ8WG.png)

How Can I implement this by using bottom sheet ? 
Or do I need to change it to Co-ordinator layout ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="120dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/v_not_to_switch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/v_to_switch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@color/colorTransparent" />


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
            xmlns:app_a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/img_top_author_icon"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/saple_user"
            app_a:civ_border_color="@color/colorWhite"
            app_a:civ_border_width="3dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/rv_article_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I created a layout and set layout behaviour as the bottom sheet behaviour. I will update the layout now

Comment: Please come up with the code.Check here:https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve